# Is there a way to specify wildcarded region names when using ehcache with hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, ehcache

When using Ehcache with Hibernate, is there a way to specify region names with wildcards in the ehcache.xml file?

For example, to allow for cache settings at the package level (with * as a wildcard indicator) where the given  setting is applied to any region that matches the wildcarded name:

```
<cache name="com.example.my.package1.*" ... />
<cache name="com.example.my.package2.*" ... />
```

(Note: The package-level distinction is just an example.  My question is to wildcards in the general case.)

Comment: This would be fantastic, as I have cacheable entities in a separate JAR from ehcache.xml, and I can't actually specify a configuration for them since the version of the other JAR is included in its name (and obviously changes frequently)

Answer (score 0):

Technically, nothing prevent you from using a wildcard in the `name` attribute of the `cache` element. After all, it's just a key as reminded in the [documentation](http://ehcache.org/documentation/configuration.html):

> Sets the name of the cache. This is used to identify the cache. It must be unique.

Will this produce the expected result? I'm not sure. As I said, it's just a key so if the idea is that Hibernate will use the region `com.example.my.package1.*` for a class `com.example.my.package1.Foo`, this won't happen automatically, you'll have to tell Hibernate to do so (the default is to use the class name for the region).

In other words, using a wildcard won't do nothing more than defining a region with a wildcard in its name.

Comment: The question is if I can specify a <cache /> setting in ehcache.xml with a wildcard operator such that the setting is applied to all regions that match the wildcarded name, not if I can have a name that happens to include an asterisk.

Comment: @bkent314 I perfectly understood the question and I suggest re-reading my answer: using a wildcard won't produce the result you expect, it will just define the name of a unique cache, nothing more.